# How can I reshape data frame by grouping certain columns

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

Say I have a R data frame with 5 columns as shown below

```
time MeanVar1 SdVar1 MedianVar1 MeanVar2 SdVar2
1 -0.8453978 -1.636985 -0.6239832 -0.4366982 -1.7037374
2 -0.3000778 -1.034199  0.3292459 -0.6606399 -0.1525361
```

Is there a neat way to make the dataFrame as follows:

```
Var time Mean/Median SD
1 1 -0.8453978 -1.636985
1 2 -0.3000778 -1.034199
1 1 -0.6239832 N/A
1 2  0.3292459 N/A 
2 1 -0.4366982 -1.7037374
2 2 -0.6606399 -0.1525361
```

or

```
Var time Mean/Median SD
MeanVar1 1 -0.8453978 -1.636985
MeanVar1 2 -0.3000778 -1.034199
MeanVar1 1 -0.6239832 N/A
MeanVar1 2  0.3292459 N/A 
MeanVar2 1 -0.4366982 -1.7037374
MeanVar2 2 -0.6606399 -0.1525361
```

My overall intention is to plot the Mean,SD for Variable 1 with errorbars, Median of Variable1 and Mean,SD for Variable 1 in a same plot. Hence, I feel that if I modify the data in such a format, I can just plot it at once rather than plotting each line separately.

With my limited knowledge of Reshape and melt, I couldn't do this.

EDIT : Adding more information

Sample Input (Given 3 rows, there are 100 rows in total):

```
Label   trainingSize    Accuracy_Mean   Accuracy_SD Accuracy_SE Precision_Mean  Recall_Mean F1  Accuracy_Median PriorClass0_Mean    PriorClass0_SD  PriorClass0_SE  ProbabilityEstimate_0given0_Mean    ProbabilityEstimate_0given0_SD  ProbabilityEstimate_0given0_SE  ProbabilityEstimate_0given1_Mean    ProbabilityEstimate_0given1_SD  ProbabilityEstimate_0given1_SE

0perc_0repeat   0.4 0.5506  0.0531  0.0038  0.6374  0.2336  0.3419  0.5372  0.5278  0.0254  0.0018  0.6433  0.0028  0.0 0.4169  0.003   0.0
0perc_0repeat   0.4 0.5456  0.0482  0.0034  0.6465  0.2142  0.3218  0.5333  0.5304  0.0248  0.0018  0.6414  0.0028  0.0 0.4193  0.0027  0.0
0perc_0repeat   0.4 0.5574  0.0555  0.0039  0.6604  0.2197  0.3297  0.5404  0.529   0.0233  0.0016  0.6436  0.003   0.0 0.4163  0.0029  0.0
```

I am trying to plot the

`1) the iteration number(1:100) in X Axis and the points of 5 columns (Accuracy_Mean, Accuracy_Median, PriorClass0_Mean, ProbabilityEstimate_0given0_Mean, ProbabilityEstimate_0given1_Mean in the Y AXIS. 
2) distribution (density obtained by 100 points) of 5 columns with error bars (either SD or SE) in a single plot using ggplot.`

I have 4 columns Precision_Mean,Recall_Mean,F1,Accuracy_Median not following the mean,sd,se pattern!

EDIT1:
1)

> dput(droplevels(head(data, 3)))
>   structure(list(Label = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "0perc_0repeat", class = "factor"), 
>       trainingSize = c(0.4, 0.4, 0.4), Accuracy_Mean = c(0.5506, 
>       0.5456, 0.5574), Accuracy_SD = c(0.0531, 0.0482, 0.0555), 
>       Accuracy_SE = c(0.0038, 0.0034, 0.0039), Precision_Mean = c(0.6374, 
>       0.6465, 0.6604), Recall_Mean = c(0.2336, 0.2142, 0.2197), 
>       F1 = c(0.3419, 0.3218, 0.3297), Accuracy_Median = c(0.5372, 
>       0.5333, 0.5404), PriorClass0_Mean = c(0.5278, 0.5304, 0.529
>       ), PriorClass0_SD = c(0.0254, 0.0248, 0.0233), PriorClass0_SE = c(0.0018, 
>       0.0018, 0.0016), ProbabilityEstimate_0given0_Mean = c(0.6433, 
>       0.6414, 0.6436), ProbabilityEstimate_0given0_SD = c(0.0028, 
>       0.0028, 0.003), ProbabilityEstimate_0given0_SE = c(0, 0, 
>       0), ProbabilityEstimate_0given1_Mean = c(0.4169, 0.4193, 
>       0.4163), ProbabilityEstimate_0given1_SD = c(0.003, 0.0027, 
>       0.0029), ProbabilityEstimate_0given1_SE = c(0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("Label", 
>   "trainingSize", "Accuracy_Mean", "Accuracy_SD", "Accuracy_SE", 
>   "Precision_Mean", "Recall_Mean", "F1", "Accuracy_Median", "PriorClass0_Mean", 
>   "PriorClass0_SD", "PriorClass0_SE", "ProbabilityEstimate_0given0_Mean", 
>   "ProbabilityEstimate_0given0_SD", "ProbabilityEstimate_0given0_SE", 
>   "ProbabilityEstimate_0given1_Mean", "ProbabilityEstimate_0given1_SD", 
>   "ProbabilityEstimate_0given1_SE"), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")

2) Expected Output is something like:

```
Vars  Label  trainingSize  Mean  SD  SE
```

Vars : Mean, PriorClass0, ProbabilityEstimate_0given0, ProbabilityEstimate_0given1; (Median, Precision, Recall, F1 not required or they can be fit to the above table with SD,SE as N/A or 0).

Comment: Also not clear why the `NA` values should come in....

Comment: Your concerns are genuine. But kindly request you not to overthink, I just want the data in such a format. NA come in because I want the breakdown the dataframe by two columns (grouping mean and sd) and since Median is not having a matching column, so to day, I want a column with N/A or 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`merged.stack` from my "splitstackshape" package handles this to a certain extent, but it recycles the values from your "SdVar" columns (so I don't get the `NA` values you show in your desired output).

Nevertheless, it might be a start to solving your problem, so here's the approach:

```
library(splitstackshape)
merged.stack(mydf, var.stubs = c("MeanVar|MedianVar", "SdVar"), sep = "var.stubs")
#    time .time_1 MeanVar|MedianVar      SdVar
# 1:    1       1        -0.8453978 -1.6369850
# 2:    1       1        -0.6239832 -1.6369850
# 3:    1       2        -0.4366982 -1.7037374
# 4:    2       1        -0.3000778 -1.0341990
# 5:    2       1         0.3292459 -1.0341990
# 6:    2       2        -0.6606399 -0.1525361
```

---

If you really want those `NA` values, perhaps this would do the trick:

```
merged.stack(
  mydf, var.stubs = c("MeanVar|MedianVar", "SdVar"), 
  sep = "var.stubs")[, SdVar := ifelse(
    duplicated(SdVar), NA, SdVar), by = time][]
#    time .time_1 MeanVar|MedianVar      SdVar
# 1:    1       1        -0.8453978 -1.6369850
# 2:    1       1        -0.6239832         NA
# 3:    1       2        -0.4366982 -1.7037374
# 4:    2       1        -0.3000778 -1.0341990
# 5:    2       1         0.3292459         NA
# 6:    2       2        -0.6606399 -0.1525361
```

Comment: Seems to be a excellent starting point, thanks! Can you explain what that one line of code does? I think that the names in VarStubs need to correspond to the column names in data frame but not exactly sure how to comprehend. I ask because my column names in the data Frame are more complicated, I just put this for simplicity (For eg. MeanVar1 = Accuracy_Mean and MeanVar2 = Parameter_Mean).... thanks!

Comment: @PraveenKumar, the `var.stubs` should be the prefixes that would comprise each variable group. Since this is based on a regular expression, we can combine groups by using the `|` symbol. Thus, if we had something like "Mean|Median", it matches the columns with both "Mean" and "Median" as part of their names. The ".time_1" variable is created from whatever is left after stripping out that part of the column name. It's hard to give you more precise response without some sample input/output from your side.

Comment: @Ananada Mahto, editted question with the exact problem and data I am trying to solve. Hope that could help you give me a precise answer. Not to hijack this question, but if you know of any other way (or data formats) by which I can get the plotting done, it would be great!

Comment: @PraveenKumar, please edit your question to include (1) the output of `dput(droplevels(head(your-data-frame, 3)))` so that your data are easily reproducible and (2) the expected output for that sample so that there is no ambiguity in terms of what you are looking for.

Comment: @Anada Mahto Added the requested edits to the question.